# error parsing stylesheet in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder

i Am getting error "error parsing stylesheet" what it is thanks for help in advance this is my code

```
<mx:Style>

.friendRendererToolTip
    {
        borderStyle : solid;
        paddingTop : 3;
        borderColor : #003300;
        fontSize : 11;
        paddingLeft : 1;
        backgroundAlpha : 1;
        paddingRight : 12;
        fontWeight : bold;
        height : 33;
        dropShadowEnabled : false;
        color : #FF0000;
        alpha : 1;
        paddingBottom : 3;
    }

    Button
    {
        borderStyle : solid;
        borderColor : #003300;
        color : blue;
        backgroundColor : #FF0000;
        cornerRadius : 0;
        fontSize : 13;
        fillAlphas : [1, 0.31, 1, 1];
    }

    .maincontainer
    {
        borderStyle : solid;
        borderColor : #003300;
        backgroundColor : #FF0000;
        cornerRadius : 5;
        verticalGap : 0;
    }

    .mainheader
    {
        paddingTop : 1;
        verticalAlign : middle;
        paddingLeft : 11;
    }

    global
    {
        color : #003300;
        fontFamily : Tahoma;
        fontSize : 13;
    }

    .cameraSlot
    {
        backgroundColor : #FF0000;
    }

    .maincontent
    {
        paddingLeft : 9;
        paddingRight : 9;
    }

    Label
    {
        color : #FF0000;
        fontSize : 13;
    }

    .sendButton
    {
        cornerRadius : 5;
    }

    ToolTip
    {
        cornerRadius : 0;
    }

    .activityArea
    {
        borderStyle : solid;
        borderColor : #FF0000;
        backgroundColor : #003300;
        disabledColor : #003300;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use fillAlpha as

```
fillAlphas : 1, 0.31, 1, 1;
```

hopes that helps

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets not needed for fillAlphas style in Button.

Use like this

```
fillAlphas : 1, 0.31, 1, 1;
```